# jscript How to change text color if p tag has a certain value AND text color is not red

Tags: jscript

I have the following p tag:

```
<p style=" color: red;">-Pepsi</p>
```

I would like to change the color of the text based on the text color and text value. So if text is Pepsi and color is not red than I would like to change the color to blue.

Till now i can check text value with the following code:

```
$('p:contains("Pepsi")').css('color', 'blue');
```

but I can not find how to check the color of the text at the same time.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is about JScript, looks like JavaScript + JQuery to me. But what about using plain JavaScript. Would that work for you?

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p")).filter(x => x.textContent.includes("Pepsi") && x.style.color != "red").forEach(x => x.style.color = "blue");
```